# Accessing label text property giving error in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am generating 10 labels on fly from code behind and I can see them when i run the page. But its giving an error when i try to access the label.text property. Its giving this error System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

```
for (int hf = 1; hf <= dfta2.Rows.Count; hf++)
                    {
                        Label lbl = new Label();
                        lbl.ID = "labeltest" + hf;
                        lbl.Text = "1";
                        lbl.ClientIDMode = System.Web.UI.ClientIDMode.Static;                                        
                        form1.Controls.Add(lbl);
                    }
     string variable3 = "labeltest" + i;

     Label lbl2 = form1.FindControl(variable3) as Label;

     lbl2.Text = "2";
```

i is just incremented by 1 every time I click the button. Any idea why its null ?

Comment: what is the value of i ?

Comment: i is equal to 1 at the start.

Comment: @A.J: are you 110% sure?

Comment: yes and i have tried like this as well variable3="labeltest5", still the same error

Comment: How do you get form1? which method are you executing this in?

Comment: <form id="form1" runat="server" >

Comment: Do you page the same problem if you use Page.Controls instead of form1.Controls?

Comment: yeah same problem, i have just checked it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you've posted must be placed inside the Page_Load or Page_Init event and verify the value of  variable *i*.

just try,

```
i=2;
string variable3 = "labeltest" + i;
Label lbl2 = form1.FindControl(variable3) as Label;
```

Comment: i=1 already, but my code is in separate function. Do i have to put it on Page_Load ?

Comment: the function is called on pageload itself

Comment: It works fine when I create labels on Page_Init function. Thanks a lot man this problem was killing me and you solved it.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your variable i == hf in the code above

Comment: If I don't use i and do it like this variable3="labeltest5", still is giving an error

Comment: what methods does you code runs from? Is for loop in Page_Load and last two lines in btn_Click?

Comment: all the code in one separate function, firstly its called once on pageload to create labels and then the function is called on button click to access lbl.text property.

Comment: Just to make sure, your for loop executes, that is dfta2.Rows.Count  is greater then 1?